# Web console for text-based RPG in Python

Tags: python, web, console-application, text-based

I'm a beginner here, slowly learning Python. I wrote a text-based RPG game, and I'm looking for a way to create a web-version of it. However, I don't want to follow the approach where HTML is generated when something happens in game (i.e. player goes to a different room, etc). Aesthetically I want a webpage with an embedded console which will run my text RPG code only, and an input field below this console to allow user input.
Which web framework should I use for this?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/ would be an easy start for you

Comment: thanks, zenpoy. I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you right you want to send the player's commands to the server asynchronously. I would suggest Pyramid because of a number of reasons:

1. It is simple to use
2. it is VERY well tested
3. It is associated with a massive community of helpful people
4. it is malleable - it does not make assumptions about what you want to do and so doesn't place restrictions on you in terms of, well, anything. You can pick your templating engine (or use more than one if you want), you can choose your database, you can choose how to talk to your database, etc

check this out:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/introduction.html